# F1 visa after graduation

Tags: transit-visas, f1-visas, connecting-flights

I am planning to move to Europe with my fiance after I graduate this summer. I would leave maybe 2 days after the program end date to Europe so I can take my things there and come back for the rest later. When I go to Europe I plan to stay there for 3 weeks then go back to my country Jamaica to apply for a transit visa in the future if I want to travel back and forth. The problem is all of the flights stop in the US before flying to Jamaica.

**Do I need to apply for a transit visa or can I use my F-1 visa to transit through the US on my way to Jamaica?**  I would have proof that I have a connecting flight to Jamaica.

I have four years until the F-1 expire and I would have recently graduated (I would not have used the 60 day grace period either since I leave 2 days after program end date).

Comment: Note that there are direct flights to Montego Bay from London Gatwick (Virgin Atlantic) and Frankfurt am Main (Condor), and to Kingston from Gatwick (British Airways).

Comment: @ThisIsMyName but an F-1 visa isn't valid after the program of study ends, expiration date notwithstanding.

Comment: @phoog To be specific, unless you are on OPT

Answer (score 2):

I think you will need to get a US transit visa (or visitor visa).

You can only enter the US on an F-1 visa if you are are joining a program of study (or are doing OPT, etc.). You had a program of study, but you have already graduated, so there is no reason for you to enter on F-1 anymore (assuming you don't have a pending OPT application or something). You can remain in status for a 60-day grace period after you graduated, but once you left the US, that ended; the grace period does not allow you to re-enter the US after you leave.

Comment: A B (visitor) visa will also work, and is more flexible while costing the same.

Comment: @phoog: added .